# How to mock a file in root folder to be modified

Tags: java, io

For some reason, I have a path (//what/ever) stored in a private variable in a class where the file is modified. So, when I test it, it tries to modify the file, but, since the file is not there, an exception is thrown.

Of course, for unit testing, I don't want to create that file in the filesystem.

Is there a way to mock that very file and force the machine to write in //my/folder instead of //what/ever?

Comment: Why not just change the value of the private variable for testing?

Comment: Because, then, when I commit the changes, the tests run by Jenkins will fail.

Comment: Have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5081738/how-to-unit-test-file-access-java. It's practically the same issue.

Comment: I still don't see what the issue is with: change the file path -> unit test -> pass unit test -> change the file path back -> commit changes.

Answer (score 0):

Mocking the file itself might be difficult. Unless, you abstract away your file handling into some interface that you manage and can inject a mock implementation during the test run. Another approach would be to expose the file path such that you can change it as part of your test setup code.

Yet another approach involves JUnit 4. In JUnit 4, you have the ability to manage temporary files and folders in your test runs. It will cleanup any new files or folders you create.

It can be done like so:

```
public class MyFileTest {
    @Rule
    public TemporaryFolder testFolder = new TemporaryFolder();

    @Test
    public void testSomething() throws IOException {
        File tempFile = testFolder.newFile("myfile");
```

I think something like this would allow you to create the actual file so your code can modify it, hence not blowing up. You might want to consider exactly the scope of your test in terms of:

- What exactly do you want to test?
- Is it that the right contents are    written to the file?
- Is it that the file itself is modified?
- etc.

Answering some of these questions might move you in the right direction of exactly what kind of test you should write and what refactoring you may need to do to facilitate the test requirements.

Comment: I thaught about the rule, but I don't see how I can tell it to go to "//what/ever". What I can do is create a temporary directory that I am sure that will be deleted, but that is not what I want. I have a file that is always in the same directory and which I want to open and analyze. So, I need to "change" the path of the file with the test.

Comment: When you say analyze in the context of the test, do you mean asserting what`s written to the file? If this is the case, could you refactor your code such that the content itself is easily testable and separated from the file creation/modification part? If you want to test that the file has been created, you could probably refactor it in a way that you provide what parent folder it is created in. This way when you write your test, part of your setup could be using the TemporaryFolder rule and passing it to your fixture.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I ended up doing... I was trying to avoid it, but I guess it's inevitable. Anyway, thanks.